# How can I select emacs autocomplete options with keyboard (not arrow keys)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I am wanting to choose from emacs autocomplete options without using the arrow keys. In vim this would be accomplished with Ctrl-n and Ctrl-p but doing the same in emacs moves me to the next line. Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to do this? I know I could probably make a keybinding for this myself but I wanted to know if there was something idiomatic already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In auto-complete you can select next candidates using <kbd>M-n</kbd> and previous candidates using <kbd>M-p</kbd>. Here is a link to the [manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Candidate_Selection)

Comment: Tab will also cycle through completion options.

Comment: Answered so fast that I can't accept the answer yet!

Comment: `Tab will also cycle through completion options`, yes you are right :)